# Kube-state-metrics error: Failed to create client: ... i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kube-state-metrics

I'm running Kubernetes in virtual machines and going through the basic tutorials, currently [Add logging and metrics to the PHP / Redis Guestbook example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook-logs-metrics-with-elk/). I'm trying to install kube-state-metrics:

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics.git kube-state-metrics
kubectl create -f kube-state-metrics/kubernetes
```

but it fails.

```
kubectl describe pod --namespace kube-system kube-state-metrics-7d84474f4d-d5dg7
```

> ...
>
> Warning  Unhealthy       28m (x8 over 30m)        kubelet, kubernetes-node1  Readiness probe failed: Get http://192.168.129.102:8080/healthz: dial tcp 192.168.129.102:8080: connect: connection refused

```
kubectl logs --namespace kube-system kube-state-metrics-7d84474f4d-d5dg7 -c kube-state-metrics
```

> I0514 17:29:26.980707       1 main.go:85] Using default collectors
>   I0514 17:29:26.980774       1 main.go:93] Using all namespace
>   I0514 17:29:26.980780       1 main.go:129] metric white-blacklisting: blacklisting the following items:
>   W0514 17:29:26.980800       1 client_config.go:549] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
>   I0514 17:29:26.983504       1 main.go:169] Testing communication with server
>   F0514 17:29:56.984025       1 main.go:137] Failed to create client: ERROR communicating with apiserver: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/version?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

I'm unsure if this 10.96.0.1 IP is correct. My virtual machines are in a bridged network 10.10.10.0/24 and a host-only network 192.168.59.0/24. When initializing Kubernetes I used the argument `--pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16` so that's one more IP range that I'd expect. But 10.96.0.1 looks unfamiliar.

I'm new to Kubernetes, just doing the basic tutorials, so I don't know what to do now. How to fix it or investigate further?

---

EDIT - additonal info:

`kubectl get nodes -o wide`

```
NAME                STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kubernetes-master   Ready    master   15d   v1.14.1   10.10.10.11   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-48-generic   docker://18.9.2
kubernetes-node1    Ready    <none>   15d   v1.14.1   10.10.10.5    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-48-generic   docker://18.9.2
kubernetes-node2    Ready    <none>   15d   v1.14.1   10.10.10.98   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-48-generic   docker://18.9.2
```

The command I used to initialize the cluster:

```
sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.59.20 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

Comment: please provide results of `kubectl get nodes -o wide` Are you using virtualbox, if yes is it bridged or host adapter mode? Did you use `--apiserver-advertise-address=` flag on kubeadm init?  I will try to recreate as with 2 ubuntu machines and kubeadm I was able to run this and it works well.

Comment: @aurelius I've added more details above, and to answer your questions: in Virtualbox I'm using both a bridged network (for internet access) and a host adapter network (because some tutorial said the nodes should be in such a network when experimenting in Virtualbox). I used --apiserver-advertise-address, more info in the post.

Comment: I've also just tried creating a cluster with NAT networking instead of a bridge (with no changes in the host-only network except for a fresh subnet). The results were the same.

Comment: Hi Rafał, if this solves the problem please accept the answer. If you have more questions related to the case feel free to ask.

Comment: @aurelius Will do, I'm looking forward to trying your solution, I just need to find some time to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is probably overlapping of Pod network with Node network - you set Pod network CIDR to 192.168.0.0/16 which your host-only network will be included into as its address is 192.168.59.0/24.

To solve this you can either change the pod network CIDR to 192.168.0.0/24 (**it is not recommended as this will give you only 255 addresses for your pod networking**)

You can also use different range for your Calico. If you want to do it on a running cluster here is an [instruction](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.6/networking/changing-ip-pools).

Also other way I tried:

edit Calico [manifest](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/manifests/calico.yaml) to different range (for example 10.0.0.0/8)  - `sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.59.20 --pod-network-cidr=10.0.0.0/8)` and apply it after the init.

Another way would be using different CNI like Flannel (which uses 10.244.0.0/16).

You can find more information about ranges of CNI plugins [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).

Comment: This worked, thank you! For simplicity I used 192.168.0.0/24. I can set up something better later, the most important thing is that it worked and the problem must have been the IP range overlap.